# Neste caso eu sou ou não obrigado a declarar as mesmas variáveis?

Tags: javascript

```js
function clock()
{
    var date = new Date();
    var dateLocate = date.toLocaleString()
    var paragraph = window.document.querySelector("#data");
    paragraph.textContent = dateLocate;
    
    window.setInterval(dateUpdate, 1000);

    function dateUpdate()
    {
        var date = new Date();
        var dateLocate = date.toLocaleString()
        var paragraph = window.document.querySelector("#data");
        paragraph.textContent = dateLocate;
    }
}

window.addEventListener("load", clock);
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>clock</title>
</head>
<body>

<div id="clock">
    <p id="data"></p>
</div>
    
</body>
</html>
```

O código acima amostra as mesmas variáveis sendo declaradas. Pois bem, se você tirar as mesmas variáveis dentro da função `clock` e deixar assim.

```
    function clock()
    {
        window.setInterval(dateUpdate, 1000);

        function dateUpdate()
        {
            var date = new Date();
            var dateLocate = date.toLocaleString()
            var paragraph = window.document.querySelector("#data");
            paragraph.textContent = dateLocate;
        }
     }

window.addEventListener("load", clock);
```

A data será atualizada automaticamente conforme a sua localidade, porém quando a página é atualizada a função `dateUpdate` será chamada depois de 1 segundo e não irar chamar de imediato, assim se eu remover as variáveis dentro da função `dateUpdate` e deixar como global desta maneira.

```
function clock()
{
     var date = new Date();
     var dateLocate = date.toLocaleString()
     var paragraph = window.document.querySelector("#data");

  window.setInterval(dateUpdate, 1000);

  function dateUpdate()
  {
      paragraph.textContent = dateLocate;
  }
}

window.addEventListener("load", clock);
```

A data aparece, mas não é atualizada acada 1 segundo, daí eu teria que voltar para o primeiro código declarando as mesmas variáveis. Como eu faria para data ser amostrada na página de imediado e sendo atualizada acada 1 segundo sem ter que repetir as variáveis?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Você não precisa de uma segunda função. Basta chamar a função `clock()` usando `setTimeout` em vez de `setInterval`. Por que `setTimeout`? Porque o `setTimeout` só roda uma vez. Se usar `setInterval`, que roda ininterruptas vezes, ao rechamar a função, irá criar um novo `setInterval` a cada segundo, e em algum momento isso irá travar o navegador.

```js
function clock()
{
    var date = new Date();
    var dateLocate = date.toLocaleString()
    var paragraph = window.document.querySelector("#data");
    paragraph.textContent = dateLocate;
    
    window.setTimeout(clock, 1000);

}

window.addEventListener("load", clock);
```

```html
<div id="clock">
    <p id="data"></p>
</div>
```

Mas se você for usar a segunda função, você teria que chamar novamente o `new Date()` para pegar a data atualizada e atualizar também a variável `dateLocate`, mas não precisaria usar `var` para isso, já que você irá apenas alterar os valores das variáveis que já foram declaradas:

```js
function clock()
{
    var date = new Date();
    var dateLocate = date.toLocaleString()
    var paragraph = window.document.querySelector("#data");
    paragraph.textContent = dateLocate;
    
    window.setInterval(dateUpdate, 1000);

    function dateUpdate()
    {
        date = new Date();
        dateLocate = date.toLocaleString()
        paragraph.textContent = dateLocate;
    }
}

window.addEventListener("load", clock);
```

```html
<div id="clock">
    <p id="data"></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Você pode simplesmente chamar sua função manualmente na primeira vez:

```
function dateUpdate()
{
    var date = new Date();
    var dateLocate = date.toLocaleString()
    var paragraph = window.document.querySelector("#data");
    paragraph.textContent = dateLocate;
}
dateUpdate();
window.setInterval(dateUpdate, 1000);
```